# Android. Font broken with caps letter T

Tags: android, fonts

Strange issue I found.
I'm using font *HouschkaRoundedAltBoldRegular.otf*

I've added it to my TextView like this.

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "HouschkaRoundedAltBoldRegular.otf");
tutorialTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Worked fine on Android until I noticed caps letter **T** is broken.
It works fine in other Windows programs (Word Office).

Here are some examples how it looks on phone.

Text: "Tutorial"

[image: "Tutorial"]

Text: "TTu Tu Th Tt To Tk ToTp"

[image: "TTu Tu Th Tt To Tk ToTp"]

As you see, it breaks if the next letter is shorter than top line of T.

It seems that its an Font + Android bug.

What can I do in this situation?

Thanks.

Edit:
In Photoshop, if you change kerning to Optical it works.

How can I change kerning on Android? Or it will be just easier to fix the font ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an interesting issue there is an interesting solution I found.

Just use Russian  Т <= Cyrillic  T <= Latin      ( http://translit.ru )

They look the same, but one works other doesn't. ( Spacing is a bit messed up but its the best solution I found )

[image]

Still I can't figure out if its fonts fault or Android, or both.